# Correction of value update in off policy TD(0)

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods

In [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/32337/how-does-this-td0-off-policy-value-update-formula-work/32339?noredirect=1#comment61239_32339) (inherited from [slides coming from D. Silver](https://www.davidsilver.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/control.pdf#page=34)) they are arguing that the value update in off policy TD(0) should be:

$$
V(S_t) = V(S_t) + \alpha \left( \frac{ \pi(A_t|S_t)}{\mu (A_t|S_t)} (R_{t+1} + \gamma V(S_{t+1})) - V(S_t) \right) 
$$

And the answer is saying that if $\pi(a|s) = 0$  then this formula will counterbalance the "overestimation"

However, I really don't see this overestimation in the derivation.

Moreover, in the RL book ok Sutton and Barto, in the off-policy td(0) (section 11.1 "Semi-gradient Methods"), they clearly states:

[image]

Here the whole error is weighted by the importance sampling ratio, which makes sense in the case $\pi(a|s)=0$, because *"if i'll never do that action, my value should not consider that branch of the tree"*

Any idea?